# Online Refund is failing in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, payment, creditmemo, refund

In my magento application, when I am trying to refund an order online, then it is failing to create credit memo and thus transaction is failing.

Can anyone suggest me possible ways to debug and come out of this issue.

Note: I checked the parameters passed to the gateway and is seems to alright but I don't know why it is sending a response 'Declined'!

Please help!

Comment: Do you have any other extension for Payment ? Please check and try to disable it and check again.

Comment: @Parth Thakkar:  I do have an extension for payment. But the thing is, it was working absolutely fine since years and now I installed a new extension Embedded ERP and just after its installation, I am unable to refund the amount online.
I even disabled the ERP extension, but then as well I am unable to refund the amount online.

Comment: Did u disabled the ERP extension from /app/etc/modules or from admin ?

Comment: @ParthThakkar: I had that module, so I did removed all the files related to that ERP module manually

I am not getting why it broke the existing functionality

Comment: Check log files in /var/log/ You will be getting the issue in system.xml or exception.log files. If log is not enabled then you can enable it from the admin System > Config > Developer > Logs . Set it to yes. and then check for the log files so that you can dig dipper for debugging the issue.

Comment: @ParthThakkar: In exception.log, I am getting this partcular error:
2016-02-24T10:16:51+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Transaction Declined: Duplicate transaction REFID:3177113920' in www.example.com/app/Mage.php:595

Can you please suggest something?
I would like to mention that after installing ERP module, this all happened even though I removed all the codes related to ERP module but I haven't removed any DB table changes done by ERP module.
Please suggest something!

Comment: Add all the files for ERP files in your code and just disable it from /app/etc/moduels as current situation might be affecting the DB. Also please tell me which payment method are you using for this ?

Comment: @ParthThakkar: I just changed the name of files in app/etc/mdules/ for ERP module but then as well the issue exists!

I am using NMI payment method (Network Merchants Inc)

Comment: Please check the tables sales_refunded_aggregated and sales_refunded_aggregated_order if your refund has been generated.

Comment: @ParthThakkar: How do we check in that table as the columns in these two tables are not having any foreign keys, so how I trace the refund?

Comment: Search for the refund ID in the whole DB then, find the entry of the refund and see what can be done further, means deleting that record along with taking care of the foreign keys and try to process refund again ??

Comment: @ParthThakkar: Can you please elaborate the step.
Why because it is unclear in those tables for which transaction those entries are made for. Let me know if I am unclear about what I am talking of but please help me, I really need help!
And I really thankyou for you are trying to help me